# Meaning of "moderates" in "Lower IQ mediates or moderates the association between childhood infection and adult psychosis"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From a [news article](https://www.healio.com/psychiatry/schizophrenia/news/online/%7Ba0cac402-bec8-41f5-a680-1633e753ceb3%7D/childhood-infection-linked-to-lower-iq-higher-risk-for-psychosis-in-swedish-men):

> “Prospective birth cohort studies suggest that childhood infections are associated with increased risk of schizophrenia in adulthood and with abnormal neurodevelopment in childhood/adolescence as measured by school grade or neurological soft signs; however, studies using IQ tests in a general population sample are rare,” Golam M. Khandaker, PhD, department of psychiatry, University of Cambridge, and colleagues wrote. “It is unclear whether lower IQ mediates or **moderates** the association between childhood infection and adult psychosis.”

I understand it thus: if lower IQ **mediates** the infection-psychosis link, this means that it is somehow relevant to the process that leads to psychosis, that lower IQ is part of the "chain of events" that result in psychosis. Some brain circuitry is sub-optimally tuned, some connections are lacking, and hence decreased IQ and, if other factors turn out unfavorably, psychosis.

But what do the authors mean by **moderates**? Can decreased IQ somehow diminish the risk of psychosis?

Comment: Merriam Webster: technical
bring about (a result such as a physiological effect).

Comment: @Lambie - I looked up **[moderate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moderate)** just now in Merriam-Webster and found nothing about **bringing about**.

Comment: We can only speculate and we also can't be sure they are using the terms exactly correctly or are using the words metaphorically in an unexpected way. It seems like the authors are trying to use them in contrast, but even after lots of thought, they don't seem like opposing ideas. 'moderate' seems to mean 'reduce the magnitude of the effect, whether positive or negative' and 'mediate' seems to mean 'be involved in the process'. It is unclear to me  how that is in opposition.

Comment: It's mediate, not moderate. I should have written that. In other words, it's unclear whether it brings it about (mediates) or lessens its intensity (moderates).

Comment: In the technical/statistical sense, the researchers are trying to say that while their work supports the inference that childhood infections, abnormal adolescent neurodevelopment (low IQ), and adult schizophrenia are related, they can't say that the causal pathway "flows" in that order. That is, it's not certain that the link between childhood infection and adult psychosis is "mediated by" or "runs through" low IQ, either in whole or in part. Maybe it does. But, it's also possible that they're related by other factors and low IQ only moderates (changes) the effect of those other relationships.

Comment: Just a quick reply to Lambie: in statistics, a moderator simply changes the strength or direction of the association between two other variables... there is no requirement or inference that it must lessen the association, tend to the null, or anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer: the authors apparently talk about mediator and moderator variables (statistics). A quote from [the Wisconsin-Madison Uni website](http://psych.wisc.edu/henriques/mediator.html):

> **Moderator variables** - "In general terms, a moderator is a qualitative (e.g., sex, race, class) or quantitative (e.g., level of reward) variable that affects the direction and/or strength of the relation between an independent or predictor variable and a dependent or criterion variable. Specifically within a correlational analysis framework, a moderator is a third variable that affects the zero-order correlation between two other variables. ... In the more familiar analysis of variance (ANOVA) terms, a basic moderator effect can be represented as an interaction between a focal independent variable and a factor that specifies the appropriate conditions for its operation." p. 1174
>
> **Mediator variables** - "In general, a given variable may be said to function as a mediator to the extent that it accounts for the relation between the predictor and the criterion. Mediators explain how external physical events take on internal psychological significance. Whereas moderator variables specify when certain effects will hold, mediators speak to how or why such effects occur." p. 1176
> The general test for mediation is to examine the relation between the predictor and the criterion variables, the relation between the predictor and the mediator variables, and the relation between the mediator and criterion variables. All of these correlations should be significant. The relation between predictor and criterion should be reduced (to zero in the case of total mediation) after controlling the relation between the mediator and criterion variables.
>
> Another way to think about this issue is that a moderator variable is one that influences the strength of a relationship between two other variables, and a mediator variable is one that explains the relationship between the two other variables. As an example, let's consider the relation between social class (SES) and frequency of breast self-exams (BSE). Age might be a moderator variable, in that the relation between SES and BSE could be stronger for older women and less strong or nonexistent for younger women. Education might be a mediator variable in that it explains why there is a relation between SES and BSE. When you remove the effect of education, the relation between SES and BSE disappears.

Comment: This is correct. The distinction between moderating and mediating variables is important in statistics generally and is a common point of discussion in any science, including (and in my experience, particularly) psychology, that makes use of statistical models.

Comment: Note that these are technical definitions for these two words and aren't necessarily what they mean outside of the statistical context.